# Powershell how to get the value of json file

Tags: powershell

I got 2 JSON files that are hash table containing a process name as key and true/false as value
I'm comparing the 2 files and I want to print to a file the process name that came out different, how can I do that?

**CODE**

```
$objects = @{
  ReferenceObject = (Get-Content -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\before.json")
  DifferenceObject = (Get-Content -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\after.json")
}

$dif = Compare-Object @objects -IncludeEqual 
foreach ($difference in $dif ){
if($difference.SideIndicator -ne '=='){
  'Process status: FAILED' > "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\Result.txt"
} else {
  'Process status: OK' > "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\Result.txt"
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using only Get-Content, Powershell 3.0 and newer has a **ConvertFrom-JSON** and **ConvertTo-JSON** cmdlets. This will help you create JSON content, and retrieve JSON content as objects.. I would recommend the following code change...

```
$objects = @{
  ReferenceObject = (Get-Content -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\before.json" -Raw | ConvertFrom-JSON)
  DifferenceObject = (Get-Content -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\after.json" -Raw | ConvertFrom-JSON)
}
```